# How to create array with arguments

Tags: javascript

```
function checkfutureMove($r,$c,$player1,$board) {


    var moveArray = new Array($r,$c);//this is correct?

    if(some condition is true) 
    {
        return moveArray; // it should return $r and $c
    }

}
```

I need to create an array which will return $r and $c.what i created is correct ? Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What exactly do you expect as output, and what exactly is the value of the parameters you're passing to your function?

Comment: Note that you don't need `$` for each parameter.

Comment: Your edit seems to markedly change the question. Originally you said *"I need to create two dimensional array having $r and $c which is for row and column."* but now you're saying *"...an array which will return $r and $c..."*? What do you actually want? A two-dimensional array, or do you mean an array with two entries in it, where one of those entries is the value `$r` and the other is the value of `$c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your *updated* question:

> I need to create an array which will return $r and $c.

If you mean an array with two entries in it (the value of `$r` and the value of `$c`), then yes, that works, although usually this is clearer:

```
var moveArray = [$r, $c];
```

---

From your *original* question:

> I need to create two dimensional array having $r and $c which is for row and column.

No, that code creates a one-dimensional array with two entries.

JavaScript doesn't have two-dimensional arrays at all, it has arrays of arrays. To create them, you have to write a loop:

```
function checkfutureMove($r,$c,$player1,$board) {
    // Create the return array
    var moveArray = [];
    var n;

    // Loop through adding entries to it
    for (n = 0; n < $r; ++n) {
        // Each entry is an array
        moveArray[n] = [];

        // This sets the length of the array (which still has no entries),
        // which you may or may not want to do.
        moveArray[n].length = $c;
    }

    // Return the result (or do something else with it)
    return moveArray;
}
```

My comment above about `length` is because standard arrays in JavaScript are inherently *sparse* (their length may be greater than the number of entries they actually contain). In fact, standard arrays in JavaScrript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're just objects with a special class of properties.